# When I fill the Acrobat Fields with chines text. text is not appearing on pdf

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itextpdf

The problem is by using the below code am able to fill the china text on Acrobat fields dynamically using iTextPdf, but when i open the generate pdf, the chines text is not displaying (When i click on the field then only it is appearing. Please refer the below code.

```
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(D://xyx.pdf);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
        AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();

        Map<String, AcroFields.Item> fields = form.getFields();
        Iterator<?> it = fields.entrySet().iterator();
        // the following block will get the china text from a txt file
        while (it.hasNext()) {

            for (int i = 0; i < chinaList.size(); i++) {
            Map.Entry<?, ?> pairs = (Map.Entry<?, ?>) it.next();
            System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
                form.setFieldProperty(chinaList.get(i), "textsize",
                        new Float(10), null);

                form.setField((String) pairs.getKey(), chinaList.get(i));
                //form.setField((String) pairs.getKey(),"Jaipal");
               System.out.println(chinaList.get(i));
            }
            it.remove(); 
            }
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("Output.pdf");
        fileOutputStream.write(decodedDocumentByteArray);
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
```

Comment: Can you share xyx.pdf because the problem could be caused by different things.

Comment: Hi Bruno Lowagie, Am not able to attach pdf here, please do test mail on pannalajaipalreddy@gmail.com my objective is to set chines characters to existing template and make it as static pdf by using  stamper.setFormFlattening(true); if you have solution share me with some sample template. and let me know the problem scenario. Please help me in this. thanks in advance...

Comment: am also using the ) itext-asian.jar BaseFont bfComic = BaseFont.createFont(PATH_FONT_ARIALUNI, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED); Please suggest me the correct way to do this.